# Can you pull an ID for future Events?

Tags: apex, email, fields, event

I've been working on an Email alert for my team that will let everyone know when something is posted on our shared public calendar. I finally got the code down to actually send the email (If you're interested: [Apex Email Trigger for a specific calendar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/55528/apex-email-trigger-for-a-specific-calendar/55566)  for the whole arduous process), but now I need help populating the email itself. I have a template loaded into Salesforce that looks like this:

```
**NEW EVENT CREATED** 

Subject: {!Event.Subject} 

Start Time: {!Event.StartDateTime} 
End Time: {!Event.EndDateTime} 

Description: {!Event.Description} 

Created By: {!Event.CreatedBy} 

Click here for more details: {!Event.Link_To_Content__c}
```

I found some code that looks like it'll do the trick, but I'm getting a "Variable Does Not Exist" error:

```
EmailTemplate newEventTemplate = [SELECT Id, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'New Event' LIMIT 1];

//Here's the error: modifiedEventId doesn't exist
        Event modifiedEvent = [SELECT Subject, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Description, Link_To_Content__c from Event WHERE Id=:modifiedEventId];

        String htmlBody = newEventTemplate.HtmlValue;
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Event.Subject}', modifiedEvent.Subject);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Event.StartDateTime}', modifiedEvent.StartDateTime);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Event.EndDateTime}', modifiedEvent.EndDateTime);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Event.Description}', modifiedEvent.Description);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Event.Link_To_Content__c}', modifiedEvent.Link_To_Content__c);
```

So here's my question: I can populate the ID fields with things that already exist (templates, users, etc), but how do I do that for something that doesn't exist yet (like an Event)?

Secondary question: Is there a way to pull the "CreatedBy" field into this? I got an error saying it wasn't a valid Event Field when I put it into the code, but there's an option for it in the template. If it's really complicated I'll just delete it, but it would be nice to have if there's a way to do it.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: "modifiedEventId doesn't exist" means you're using the wrong variable name. And yes, you must save the record before you know its ID. Finally, CreatedBy is a relationship. The normal email template merges relationships automatically, but in Apex Code, you'll need to be more explicit, such as "modifiedEvent.CreatedBy.FirstName", and you need to query that data first.

Comment: oooh, thanks for the heads up about CreatedBy. It likes that much more. I guess the better question about how to populate the event fields would be what would that variable look like if it's populating from a future event?